# placing subscript under \max in \frac

Tags: math-mode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\max_i\frac{1}{\max_i}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

results in i beeing placed as intended outside `\frac`, but not beeing placed under the max operator inside the fraction.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your document does not compile. It misses either `amsmath` or `mathtools` package

Comment: Added amsmath package. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\max\limits_i}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alternately, one could use `\frac{1}{\displaystyle\max_i}`.  The issue is that inside a `\frac`, things are not, by default `\displaystyle` (equation style) but instead `\textstyle` (inline style).  One must explicitly tell the `\frac` argument to present itself in `\displaystyle`.

Comment: You can make your post display as text by indenting it 4 characters, or alternately by highlighting it in the edit box and clicking the `{}` symbol above the box.  As SoundsOfSilence noted, you should provide complete working code.  I have edited your answer to do so.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, please give the first-time poster some slack, as it is clear that Twonky is posting in good faith.  Be a coach, not a law-enforcement officer.